# Get schema of the result returned by select query

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008-r2, relational-database

Can we get schema of the result returned by SELECT Query? Below code:

```
string SQLQuery = "SELECT DISTINCT c.name 'Column Name',  t.Name 'Data type' FROM" +
                   " sys.columns c INNER JOIN " +
                   " sys.types t ON c.system_type_id = t.system_type_id" +
                   " LEFT OUTER JOIN " +
                   " sys.index_columns ic ON ic.object_id = c.object_id AND ic.column_id = c.column_id" +
                   " LEFT OUTER JOIN" +
                   " sys.indexes i ON ic.object_id = i.object_id AND ic.index_id = i.index_id" +
                   " WHERE" +
                   " c.object_id = OBJECT_ID('[DB].[dbo].[" + ddlTable.SelectedItem.Text + "]') AND t.name <> 'sysname'";
```

This code returns column names along with datatype for specified table. My requirement is to get column names along with datatype from a select query rather than directly specifying table name. like

```
  string SQLQuery = "SELECT DISTINCT c.name 'Column Name',  t.Name 'Data type' FROM" +
                       " sys.columns c INNER JOIN " +
                       " sys.types t ON c.system_type_id = t.system_type_id" +
                       " LEFT OUTER JOIN " +
                       " sys.index_columns ic ON ic.object_id = c.object_id AND ic.column_id = c.column_id" +
                       " LEFT OUTER JOIN" +
                       " sys.indexes i ON ic.object_id = i.object_id AND ic.index_id = i.index_id" +
                       " WHERE" +
                       " c.object_id = OBJECT_ID('SELECT col1, col2 from table(s)') AND t.name <> 'sysname'";
```

Though this doesn't work.

Comment: Will this query be consumed by any application? Like a C# application or similar?

Comment: @PeterHenell Yes. It'll be.

Comment: Depending on why you need this information the answer might be different. Why do you need to get the meta data of a query result?

Comment: @PeterHenell I am working with SharePoint. Requirement is to populate the result of a select query into SharePoint list. Schema of list and data will be dynamically created.

Answer (score 3):

You can SELECT the query result INTO a temporary table, and from that table get the metadata. If you choose a solution like this you will need to make sure that the name of the temporary table is UNIQUE per call, otherwise meta-data in information_schema views will be shared across the sessions.

```
if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmp') is not null drop table #tmp

select * 
into #tmp
from Customer where 1 = 0 
-- select with a false predicate in order to ONLY get
--     metadata of the query and no rows of data.

select * from #tmp
-- Then select metadata from information_schema view
select COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE from tempdb.information_schema.columns where TABLE_NAME like '#tmp%'

Result:
CustomerId  int
CustomerType    int
Name    nvarchar
IsActive    bit
```

Or, if you want you can do it easier In C# which will probably less error prone. It is very easy to get the meta-data for a result set of a query:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string connStr = "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks;Integrated Security=True";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Orders where 1 = 0", new SqlConnection(connStr));

            SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ad.FillSchema(ds, SchemaType.Mapped);
            var metaTable = ds.Tables[0];

            foreach (DataColumn col in metaTable.Columns)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}", col.DataType, col.ColumnName);
            }

         }
```

Output:

```
System.Int32 : OrderId
System.Int32 : CustomerId
System.Int32 : ArticleId
System.Decimal : TotalAmount
System.DateTime : OrderDate
```

Comment: I would suggest adding PRECISION and SCALE to the column list for the `information_schema` select

Answer (score 2):

I know this question targeted SQL 2008 but it's handy to know for 2012+ there's an inbuilt stored procedure called sp_describe_first_result_set that will get the desired results.

See the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-describe-first-result-set-transact-sql)

Comment: Thanks for sharing, Jeff

Answer (score 0):

It looks from your examples like you're working in C# or something similar.  Assuming that you're trying to get the schema data for the purpose of doing things in your program and not building an SQL-only mechanism, I may have a solution.

Given an arbitrary `SELECT` query we can get the schema using [SqlDataReader.GetSchemaTable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getschematable.aspx).

Unfortunately we need to execute the query, but we can reduce the impact somewhat by cutting the output to 0 rows.  Assuming we'll always have a `SELECT` statement with no `TOP <n>` clause you could use:

```
var sql = "SELECT TOP 0 " + query.SubString("SELECT ".Length);
```

Alternatively you could just wrap the whole thing in an outer `SELECT` like so:

```
var sql = "SELECT TOP 0 * FROM (" + query + ") qq";
```

This catches most forms and it should be fairly obvious what it is doing.

From here we create a `DbCommand` for the query and open a `DbDataReader` instance to get the schema.  The schema will go into a `DataTable` that you can then read for output.

```
DataTable schema;

using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
{
    command.CommandText = sql;
    using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        schema = reader.GetSchemaTable();
}
```

At this point `schema` contains a row for each field in your query with all the information you might need.

I added this extension method for one of my own programs:

```
public static Dictionary<string, (Type DataType, bool AllowDBNull, bool IsReadOnly)> GetQuerySchema(this IDbConnection connection, string query)
{
    var conn = connection as DbConnection;
    if (conn == null)
        return null;

    if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
        conn.Open();

    string sql;
    if (query.StartsWith("SELECT"))
        sql = "SELECT TOP 0 * FROM (" + query + ") qq";
    else
        sql = "SELECT TOP 0 * FROM " + query;

    DataTable schema;
    using (var command = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        command.CommandText = sql;
        using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            schema = reader.GetSchemaTable();
    }

    var res = 
        schema.Rows.OfType<DataRow>()
        .ToDictionary
        (
            _ => _.Field<string>("ColumnName"),
            _ => 
            (
                _.Field<Type>("DataType"),
                _.Field<bool>("AllowDBNull"),
                _.Field<bool>("IsReadOnly")
            )
        );
    return res;
}
```