# Database - Schema of columns selected in the query Using Java

Tags: java, sql-server, database, db2, schema

**Problem Statement:**

What is the optimal way to get the schema of columns in the select clause (column names, types) of a query using java?

**Options**

1. One option is to run the query and then use ResultSetMetadata to get the column name and the type, but i am not sure if this is going to be optimal as it would run the entire query. Even with the limit clause, it may still run the entire query before the results are limited. Would there be any performance difference between queries with and without limit clause?
2. Another option is per the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21929572/get-schema-of-the-result-returned-by-select-query) i.e. giving a false condition to the query and use the ResultSetMetaData.

> For example, select * from A where 1=0;

Any other better way or option 2 is the most optimal in all cases? i.e. I may have a query that joins multiple tables, would option 2 makes sense in this case too when i add a false condition at the end?

Note: Need the solution for DB2 and SqlServer.

EDIT:
Also, would the order in which the schema is fetched match with the column order in data? 
i.e. If i do a select * from A, lets say i get 5 columns. Would this order match with when i get the schema using ResultSetMetadata using the same query?

Comment: It's not a good idea to code `select *` in Java. You should always prepare your statement and explicity specify your return columns. This way you don't even need to check the metadata. (source: https://blog.jooq.org/2013/08/12/10-more-common-mistakes-java-developers-make-when-writing-sql/)

Comment: But i need all columns

Comment: from java your using JDBC resultset.  So your option two would seem to work on any database.

Comment: Ok and what about the order in which i get the schema, would it match with the order in which i get the data?